# Elmah log entry does not include Server Variables

Tags: elmah

I Log my errors in Elmah using `ErrorLog.GetDefault` because I want to use the ErrorId. However when I do this the Server Variables are not included in the log entry. Could anyone explain why and if possible, how to fix this?

```
public void LogExceptionToElmah(Exception exception)
{
    //Includes Server Variables
    ErrorSignal.FromContext(HttpContext.Current).Raise(exception);

    //Does not include Server Variables
    var elmahId = Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(HttpContext.Current).Log(new Error(exception));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this by including `HttpContext.Current` into the Elmah Error.

```
var elmahId = ErrorLog.GetDefault(HttpContext.Current).Log(new Error(exception, HttpContext.Current));
```

I still wonder why the `ErrorLog.GetDefault` requires a `HttpContext` as it doesn't seem to do anything with it.